# React - variable is undefined instead of true/false - component gets rendered first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

Alright, so what I'm trying to achieve is a function, that returns a Button with a different label depending on wether a file exists, or not. So far so good, the code itself seems to be working, but in the wrong order. 
What i did is print out 'file does exist' or 'does not exist' in the part of the function that does the actual checking, saving a `boolean` to a `test` variable, using said variable to determine which button gets returned in the end.

Now what happens it that, even if the first part prints out 'file does exist' (which should save `true` to `test`), `console.log(test)`a bit further down returns `undefined` which, of course, results in the conditional not to work.

I am sure I'm overlooking something very simple but I just can't figure it out.

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import fs from 'fs';

var ConfigChecker = React.createClass({

  render: function(){

    var test;
    fs.open('./App.js', 'r', (err, fd) => {
      if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
          console.log('file does not exist');
          test = false;
        }

        throw err;
      }
      console.log('this should be executed first:');
      console.log('file does exist')
      test = true;
    });


    if (test)
    {
      console.log("this should be executed last:");
      console.log(test);
      return (<RaisedButton label="true" />);
    }
    else {
      console.log("this should be executed last:");
      console.log(test);
      return (<RaisedButton label="false" />);
    }
  }


});

export default ConfigChecker;
```

[this is what gets returned in the dev console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pCK8.png)

Comment: fs.open is async, try using fs.openSync

Comment: I would like to know more about that, how would the actual code itself have to be changed? The documentation on the function is a bit confusing to me, would you mind showing me?

Answer (score 2):

Async calls do not work as you think they do.  Anytime you see a function which is async (expects a callback, returns a Promise) in JavaScript prefix the function's name in your mind with "registerInterestIn{functionName}".  So `fs.open` becomes `fs.registerInterestInOpen`.

With that in mind, your code now looks like this:

```
var test;
fs.registerInterestInOpen('./App.js', 'r', ...);
// Still undefined here, we just registered an interest
// in the results of opening ./App.js ... nothing has
// actually *happened* yet.
if (test) {

} else {

}

// And when we get down here, JavaScript will actually *do*
// the opening, and call our callback with the result, when
// the operating system gets back to us with the data or an error
```

#### How to handle this issue then?

You'll need to use a bit of React state so you know which of the three states your component is in (waiting to find out if the file exists, the file exists, the file does not exist).  Then you need to change your state in the callback to `fs.open` to tell React to re-render your component:

```
const ConfigChecker = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { test: null };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    fs.open('./App.js', 'r', (err, fd) => {
      if (err && err.code === 'ENOENT') {
        console.log('file does not exist');
        return this.setState(() => { test: false});
      }
      this.setState(() => { test: true});
    });
  },
  render() {
    if (this.state.test == null) {
      return 'Loading ...';
    } else {
      return <RaisedButton label={this.state.test} />;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Heh, I should have continued the codecademy course before asking then, my bad.Many thanks to you too, this made it clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import fs from 'fs';

var ConfigChecker = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      test: true
    }
  },

  // or componentWillMount() should work
  componentDidMount: function(){
    var test;
    var self = this;
    fs.open('./App.js', 'r', (err, fd) => {
      if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
          console.log('file does not exist');
          self.setState({
            test: false
          });
          // test = false;
        }

        throw err;
      }
      console.log('this should be executed first:');
      console.log('file does exist')
      self.setState({
        test: true
      });
      // test = true;
    });
  },

  render: function(){
    if (this.state.test)
    {
      console.log("this should be executed last:");
      console.log(test);
      return (<RaisedButton label="true" />);
    }
    else {
      console.log("this should be executed last:");
      console.log(test);
      return (<RaisedButton label="false" />);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, this did it! Looks like a tiny bit from my own code was missing but now it runs fine. Thanks alot.

Comment: Ok. Glad to help      .